# Is there any way to create an indexed data collection in Prolog?

Tags: database, arrays, indexing, prolog

Thinking of creating a database in Prolog, using a list seems obviously ineffective. So what I'd like to know is if it's possible somehow to get access to elements by their index or not and how, theoretically, a large database could be made.

Another subject I'm curious about is how to implement a simple task like that:
Assume we have 2 arrays
A [1,3,5,2,6,4] and B ["a","b","d","e","c","f"]
The goal is to bind letters to numbers and then sort both arrays to get
A [1,2,3,4,5,6] and B ["a","e","b","f","d","c"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the index, you'd probably be better off representing the list as a collection of facts, something like `isAtIndex( index, valueAtIndex )` for each element.  Presumably, then, Prolog would use whatever indexing mechanism it has to match the appropriate fact you want (that is, ask it to prove `isAtIndex(3,Value)` and it will bind Value to the matching value).

Similarly for your second question: you'd walk the 2 arrays in concert, asserting something like `pair(valueFromA, valueFromB)` for each.  Then you could create a sorted version of A, and you're all set.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the database question: It is very common to use Prolog facts to store data. SWI-Prolog and other systems automatically build dynamic indices to support fast access to such collections. Regarding the second question, use for example `keysort/2` on the term [1-"a",3-"b",...,4-"f"]. See pairs_keys_values/3 and related predicates in library(pairs).